# Unexpected characters in output

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

I am having the following issue.

This code is giving me somehow wrong output.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
//setup php for working with Unicode data
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","test","test");
mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8", $con );
mysql_query( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $con );
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "this is a test";
?>
```

This happened to all my files automatically. I haven't updated anything on my server.

Please help! Is driving me crazy!

I send the data to an iphone app and i get an \n in front of the text like this:

```
\nthis is a test
```

What is going on?

Any help appreciated

Comment: A rogue `\n` in an auto-prepend file?

Comment: Is sent automatically i haven't changed nothing on the client or server side!

Comment: No need for shouting... _is_ there an `auto-prepend` file? Can you examine that `auto-prepend` file?

Comment: I am sorry i am struggling for hours to understand what is going on. How should i examine the auto-prepend file. Could you please tell me?

Comment: Done. I get this...auto_prepend_file /tmp/.tmp.err /tmp/.tmp.err

Comment: So, try to read that file's contents, but better yet: try to find out where this auto_prepend is set (.htaccess, webserver config, php.ini files etc.), because this seems silly to autoprepend.... Or at any rate: remove the contents from that thing, but not before you've looked at it to make sure it isn't a security breach of some kind.

Comment: Hmmm that explains everything! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply this KB article http://kb.parallels.com/115025